# Mapping cone is a functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

It is a well-known general fact that in a triangulated category, the cone $Z$ of a morphism $X \longrightarrow Y$ (that means there exists a distinguished triangle $X \longrightarrow Y \longrightarrow Z \longrightarrow X[+1]$) is not functorial though it is unique up to an isomorphism.

Let $F,G,H: \mathcal{T}_1 \longrightarrow \mathcal{T}_2$ be triangulated functors between triangulated categories, assume that there are natural transformations
$$ F \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow H \longrightarrow F[+1].$$
We say this sequence is distinguished if it is distinguished objectwise.

My question is very simple: assume that only $F,G$ are functors and $H$ is defined objectwise
$$H(A) =  \mathrm{Cone}(F(A) \longrightarrow G(A))$$
then under which conditions $H$ can be turned into a functor?

Here is an example. Let $j: U \longrightarrow X$ be an open immersion of schemes and let me denote by $D^+(-)$ the derived category of complexes of sheaves on the étale sites. Then the cone of the unit transformation ${id}\longrightarrow j_*j^*$ is a functor. We can proceed the proof as follows.

First for each object $A \in D^+(X)$, we choose a cone $C(A) = \mathrm{Cone}(A \longrightarrow j_*j^*(A))$ and we prove that for every morphism $A \longrightarrow B$ in $D^+(X)$, there exists a unique morphism $f: C(A) \longrightarrow C(B)$ making the obvious diagram of triangles commutative. Suppose otherwise that there exist two such, namely, $f,g: C(A) \longrightarrow C(B)$. Then $f-g$ belongs to the kernel $\mathrm{Hom}(C(A),C(B)) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(C(A),B[+1])$. This kernel is $\mathrm{Hom}(C(A),j_*j^*(B))$ because $\mathrm{Hom}(C(A),-)$ is a cohomological functor. Therefore it suffices to prove this abelian group is zero and by adjunction we need $\mathrm{Hom}(j^*C(A),j^*(B))=0$. This is the point since $j^*C(A)=0$ is the cone of $j^*(A) \longrightarrow j^*j_*j^*(A)$ (which is an isomorphism since $j$ is an immersion).

One can see in the proof above that we use the fact $j$ is an immersion and without any knowledge of its (closed) complement (if one defines $i: Z = X \setminus U \longrightarrow X$ then $C(A)$ is simply $i_*i^!A[+1]$) so I hope that there will be a general method or some list of special conditions (for two-out-of-three terms $F,G,H$) that can turn the remainder into a functor.

Any reference and suggestion are appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The cone of $F\to G$ can be made functorial if $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ are the homotopy categories of stable infinity categories (or dg categories, or suitable model categories...) and $F\to G$ is likewise induced by a natural transformation between two functors between the enhancements. This is what most often happens in practice, i.e. in the situation you describe.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I usually work with model categories, I wonder whether you have any reference for the model categories context?

Comment: I don't, but I think it should follow by describing the cone of $F(A)\to G(A)$ as the homotopy pushout of $0\leftarrow F(A)\to G(A)$.

Comment: In terms of a reference, the first chapter of Higher algebra is unusually friendly and goes over the infinity categorical perspective on derived categories etc.

Comment: @LeoHerr I have checked Higher algebra, it seems that none of its parts deal with functoriality of the cone